# if http:// is in string then leave it, else if not add it

Tags: php

I have a input that you enter a URL, i basically want to write some php that says if the domain containts "http://" then leave it be, else if not then add it to the beginning.
This is what I have so far...

```
$domain = $_POST["domain"];

if (strpos($domain, "http://")) {
return $domain;
} else {
$domain = "http://" . $domain;
}
```

This doesnt seem to work..

it doesnt add the http:// on if it doesnt contain http://.

Comment: Why does one return `$domain`, and the other change its value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "http://" then leave it be, else if not then add it to the beginning.

How about adding adding it regardless? I find that to be easier:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.google.com';
echo 'http://' . preg_replace( '~^http://~', '', $url );
```

Comment: perhaps an explanation please?

Answer (score 6):

you forgot to return $domain.

```
$domain = $_POST["domain"];

if (strpos($domain, "http://") !== false) {
return $domain;
} else {
return "http://" . $domain;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the string starts with `http://`, `strpos` will return `0`, which will evaluate to false.

Change the if statement to:

```
if(strpos($domain, "http://") !== FALSE){
```

Answer (score 2):

read [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> This function may return Boolean
>   FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to
>   FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read
>   the section on Booleans for more
>   information. **Use the === operator** for
>   testing the return value of this
>   function.

Answer (score 2):

That is because strpos will return the location of the string, within the string.
In your url, that is 0. Which equals to false. Make it a strict check - add === false.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strpos($domain, "http://") !== false) {
//return substr($domain,7); Thanks Rocket. 
return $domain;
} else {
return "http://" . $domain;
}
```

Comment: `!= false` should be `!== false`.  If the string starts with `http://`, `strpos` will return `0`, which evaluates to `false`.

Comment: What's with the `substr` call?

Comment: It was becouse of a misunderstanding, substr function is used here to remove http characters, but I guess AJFMEDIA does not want it to be removed. so I'm gonna edit the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late to the party, but I prefer this approach:

```
if (!preg_match('#^http[s]{0,1}://#', $input)) {
    $input = 'http://' . $input;
}
```

This will preserve a https:// address, and not have you ending up with `http://https://www.mysite.com`. You could also further edit it to strip out https:// if you had a rule for not using https addresses.

I know the original question didn't ask for this, but I think it's important to consider in most situations, and will hopefully help someone else who comes looking.

Answer (score 0):

Use caution when using strpos(). It will return 0 when 'http://' is found at the beginning of the string, causing your if statement to fail unexpectedly. You will want to check the type of the return to be sure:

```
$domain = $_POST["domain"];

if (FALSE !== strpos($domain, "http://")) {
    return $domain;
} else {
    return "http://" . $domain;
}
```

Comment: Hi, strpos will return the location of the first occurrence, or false if it isn't there. This means it will *never* return the bool true.

Comment: `strpos` **NEVER** returns `TRUE`.  It will return the location of the string or `FALSE` if not found.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Corrected.