# change non http value to http url in text field using php

Tags: php, url

How can I add a 'http://' component to a post variable so that it automatically adds that part so if someone submits: '`www.1webtutor.in`' is will register as `http://www.1webtutor.in`.

Change non-http value in text field to http value when someone insert value as above.

in the form at "`http://1webtutor.in/tools/test/`"

```
<input type="text" name="sitehost">
```

Comment: Can you show your `<form>` code so we can see the name of the `<input>`

Comment: better possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111934/if-http-is-in-string-then-leave-it-else-if-not-add-it or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240414/add-http-prefix-to-url-when-missing

Comment: <input type="text" name="sitehost" value="<?=$sitehost;?>"> <input type="submit" value="submit"></p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `substr` which for your future references can be used to start from the end if you start using negative values.

```
<input name="sitehost" type="text" value="<?php
if (substr($sitehost,0,7)!='http://') {echo 'http://';}
?>" />
```

The [php.net/substr](http://php.net/substr) page has more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
    <?php
    $url    =   'www.1webtutor.in';
    if (strpos($url,'http://') === false){
        $url = 'http://'.$url;
    }
    echo $url;
    ?>
<input type="text" name="sitehost" value='<?php echo $url; ?>'>
```

[Ref Click here](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: Thank u very much,I fixed the Issue.